# How to address the artifact I want to upload?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am using Actions to compile an executable and then [upload](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) it:

```
name: note
on: push
jobs:
  cli:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./cli
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - run: go build -v
      - run: dir
      - name: upload cli.exe
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: cli.exe
          path: cli.exe
```

This results in:

[image]

The `dir` command shows that `cli.exe` is there, but it seems that I do not address it correctly for the upload. How to fix that?

Comment: Please show the commands you have tried, as text. I am not sure that uploading executables is worthwhile on github. Read Levine's book on [*Linkers and loaders*](https://www.amazon.com/Linkers-Kaufmann-Software-Engineering-Programming/dp/1558604960). *Artifacts* may mean something you cannot build easily from other data (in particular source code files for [Go](https://go-lang.org/)...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: *Please show the commands you have tried, as text* → these are not commands, this is a GitHub workflow in Actions. The screenshot is from GitHub. As for providing executables in GitHub: this is going to be an open-source project with executables intended for end-users that do not want/know how to compile them. And I found this issue.

Comment: You could publish the executable files on some other website, and put on GitHub some hyperlink to them. Be aware than an executable for Windows 7 might not work on Windows 10 and vice versa. In France, websites are cheap (e.g. at [OVH](https://ovh.com/) less than 20€/month, and 5€/month at [kimsufi](https://www.kimsufi.com/fr/)....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path of the upload must be provided from the root of the checked-out repo. In my case, the upload section needs therefore to be

```
- name: upload cli.exe
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: cli.exe
      path: cli/cli.exe
```

In other words, `actions/upload-artifact` does not take into account the `working-directory` setting.